# How to create a vector sequencing along nonNA elements

Tags: r, vector, sequence, na

In R, given a vector with some elements as NA, how can I count along it skipping NAs? 
For example:

```
let <- letters[1:10]
let[c(2,3,7,9)] <- NA
```

How would I get the vector?

```
1,NA,NA,2,3,4,NA,5,NA,6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using `seq_along`

```
let[!is.na(let)] <- seq_along(let[!is.na(let)])
as.numeric(let)
# [1]  1 NA NA  2  3  4 NA  5 NA  6
```

---

**benchmark**

```
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 1e7
let_long <- seq_len(n)
set.seed(1)
let_long[sample(seq_len(n), size = 1e6)] <- NA

benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  Karolis = Karolis(let_long),
  Markus = Markus(let_long),
  Snoram = Snoram(let_long),
  Alexandra = Alexandra(let_long),
  Frank = Frank(let_long) # see comment under Snoram's answer
)
```

To get the chart below, type `autoplot(benchmark)`.

[image]

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   Karolis 1042.0708 1216.6241 1314.9765 1290.3428 1374.7090 1807.4604   100
#    Markus  210.3860  259.9957  310.0776  293.8244  363.4317  488.2171   100
#    Snoram  714.4514  938.5760 1033.6168 1029.8205 1104.5614 1546.3733   100
# Alexandra 4317.5206 4470.2634 4665.9004 4603.6446 4771.5768 6495.3595   100
#     Frank  103.3624  126.2842  166.7555  159.3568  190.5186  290.0422   100
```

Functions compared so far.

```
Karolis <- function(x) {
  match(seq_along(x), which(!is.na(x)))
}

Markus <- function(x) {
  x[!is.na(x)] <- seq_along(x[!is.na(x)])
  as.numeric(x)
}

Snoram <- function(x) {
  ifelse(is.na(x), NA, cumsum(!is.na(x)))
}

Alexandra <- function(x) {
  j = 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if(is.na(x[i]) == FALSE){
      j = j + 1
      x[i] <- j
    }
  }
  as.numeric(x)
}

Frank <- function(x) {
  replace(cumsum(!is.na(x)), is.na(x), NA)
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the microbenchmark package; how do I get the chart?

Comment: @CTHall Use the `autoplot` function.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to match all the indices of `let` to the non-na indices:

```
> match(seq_along(let), which(!is.na(let)))
 [1]  1 NA NA  2  3  4 NA  5 NA  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Other options include:

Use `ifelse()` and `cumsum()`

```
ifelse(is.na(let), NA, cumsum(!is.na(let)))
#[1]  1 NA NA  2  3  4 NA  5 NA  6
```

Comment: Just be careful, since we are doing a sequence eg. try when you have `let = c(NA,1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,1)`

Comment: @Onyambu thanks, the first solution will fail on this and the third will look silly (nchar() on a numeric).

Comment: Another way of writing the same thing: `replace(cumsum(!is.na(let)), is.na(let), NA)`

Answer (score 0):

This would get the result you are looking for but isn't efficient

```
let <- letters[1:10]
let[c(2,3,7,9)] <- NA

j = 0
for (i in 1:length(let)) {
  if(is.na(let[i]) == FALSE){
    j = j + 1
    let[i] <- j
    }
}
```